# why are the quotes breaking in src when there is a space

Tags: jquery, ajax, src

I have an issue with my code and cant seem to search out an answer for. I have an ajax section where I am trying to load a picture from a folder that has spaces in the name. I check the source code and I see the src is breaking where there is a space. How would I get the src from breaking quotes everytime there is a space. Please help. Here is my example:

```
pic1="gallery/3d Models/mazeLevel1.jpg";

images+= row+"<td class="+tdMargin+" id='tdName' value="+i+"><div  

class="+sl+" ><img src="+pic1+"  width='50px'   class='slidePics' 

></img></div></td>";
```

I am getting src="gallery/3d" models/mazeLevel1.jpg and it is not loading.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap image src attribute value in quotes

Use

```
 sl+" ><img src='"+pic1+"'  width='50px'   class='slidePics' "
                ^        ^
```